# Print Multiplication Table Using function in PHP

Tags: php

This my coding I'm not getting my answer via Infunction Value '$z'. Please Help

```
<form action="functions.php" method="post">


<input type="text" name="math">

</form>

<?php

$x = $_POST['math'];


function table($x, $y) {

    $z = $x * $y;
    return $z;


}

for ($y = 1; $y <=10; $y++) {


    echo $x ."*". $y ."=". "<br>";

}
```

Comment: You no where called your function so how you will get any response from it?

Comment: Where did you call `table($x, $y)` function in your code?

Comment: @PankajMakwana When i was calling my function using echo table(); i was getting the notice "Undefined Constant table";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call your function to get the output like below:-

```
for ($y = 1; $y <=10; $y++) {
    $output = table($x, $y);
    echo $x ."*". $y ."=". $output . "<br>";
}
```

A sample output:- https://eval.in/872649

***You  need to wrap php code inside `isset()` like below:-***

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['math'])){
    $x = $_POST['math'];

    function table($x, $y) {
        $z = $x * $y;
        return $z;
    }
    for ($y = 1; $y <=10; $y++) {
        $output = table($x, $y);
        echo $x ."*". $y ."=". $output . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: @shoaib.ahmed92  also check the enhancement in your php code

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your loop as below.. You don't have call the function `table` anywhere in your code. call it in loop

```
for ($y = 1; $y <=10; $y++) {

    $z = table($x, $y);
    echo $x ."*". $y ."=".$z ."<br>";

}
```